# Performance Queries on a SQL table that has 200 million rows in it?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have a table that has 200 million rows and it will increase by 1.5 million every day.

I need to query on it to fetch the data for a period say like 3 months data, which is taking atleast half an hour time to retrieve it.

Is there any way of performance fine tuning the table or query to execute and get the data much faster in less than a minute or 2.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Chnl](
    [Id] int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL 
        CONSTRAINT [PK_Chnl] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    ,[ChnlNo] int NOT NULL
    ,[ChnlName] varchar(50) NULL
    ,[Active] bit NULL
)

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ChnlData]( 
    [Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL
        CONSTRAINT [PK_ChnlData] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED
    ,[ChnlId] [int] NOT NULL
    ,[ChnlValue] [decimal](6, 2) NOT NULL
    ,[ChnlDataLogTime] [datetime] NOT NULL
    ,[Comments] [varchar](max) NULL
    ,[Active] [bit] NULL
    ,CONSTRAINT [FK_ChannelData_Channel] FOREIGN KEY([ChnlId]) REFERENCES [dbo].[Chnl] ([Id]) 
)
```

Its just a simple query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [ChnlData]
WHERE  ChnlId in (519, 520)
```

It fetches 7 million records and it took 9 minutes to get that. Right now the DB size is 32 Gigabytes

Comment: Please add details regarging table structure and sample data. What have you tried to do to increase performance? What is "crore" and "lakh"?

Comment: "fine tuning the table or query". What table definition? What query?

Comment: Tunning depends a lot on your datastructure. Try to post more specific questions. A short answer is: probably yes and ill demand a lot of work and learning effort from you. Try to fine tunning indexes, re design tables, views, rewrite SP, tunning isolation level for each query, etc.

Comment: Sorry about that, 1.5 million records will be inserted every day into the table and it already has 20 million records in it. The table structure is,

Comment: @Rama 1.5 million * 30 days *  3 months = 135 million rows. If we assume that the average row size is about 40 bytes and simple query to one table it means the server needs to process about 5.5 Gigabytes. What is your hardware? And the question still is meaningless without the publication of the query

Comment: Thank You Martin, I missed it ...

Comment: Its just a simple query, select * from ChnlData where ChnlId in (519, 520). It fetches 7 million records and it took 9 minutes to get that. Right now the DB size is 32 Gigabytes.

Comment: @Rama Did you have index on Table [ChnlData], column [ChnlId]? Something like `CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_ChnlData_ChnlId] ON [dbo].[ChnlData] ([ChnlId])`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Partitioning your table (year or month based) will be one of the possible solutions. You may have to create scripts for dynamic partitions.

You may implement DataWarehousing style of solutions in addition to the previous approach.
Like you may create a surrogate key(Unique key - may be a sequence) for evry record, and prepare a look up table like structure.

Ex: Keys 1234M - 1235M set of keys will be in XX Partition.. etc.

This may not be easily implementable. But it is a clean solution.

For OLTP environments, patition table only will help a lot.

Allocate a separate database for tis data. And using parallel queries(empolying multiple nodes processors), we can speed up the query output.

Answer (score 0):

First and foremost I would create an index to cover your search parameters, at the very least this should cover the column that contains your date. If that's not enough, you might want to look into Maheswaran's suggestion and use partitioning and filegroups, which works especially well with indexes as they can cover each partition separately.

But all in all it's really hard to say as your question is way too broad. How many columns and which types of data are fetched from the table, what's the total amount of columns in the table? What are the filters in your WHERE clause (your index will use these filters). How much data in size would your 3-month batch contain (could be viable to create filegroups per each 3 month period making it easier to archive and use bulk operations against said data). Etc.

There's too much guessworks to be done right now.

Edit: Since the numbers changed to far less than what you originally had, a simple index could be quite sufficient for now. Try this:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX CHLNDATA_QUARTER_IDX ON ChnlData (ChnlId, ChnlDataLogTime)
```

Then if you want the data for the past three months for instance, you can get it like so:

```
SELECT * 
FROM [ChnlData]
WHERE  ChnlId in (519, 520)
AND YEAR(ChnlDataLogTime) IN (YEAR(DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE())), YEAR(GETDATE()))
AND MONTH(ChnlDataLogTime) BETWEEN MONTH(DATEADD(MONTH, -3, GETDATE())) AND MONTH(GETDATE())
```

Didn't check the syntax but that should be right or close enough.

Comment: Wrapping `ChnlDataLogTime` in functions is not sargable or optimal.